# Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand in flask

Tags: python, html, flask, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to develop a data application with flask. After loading the dataset, I want to selectively train the x and y columns of the data myself. But I'm getting this error.
"Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."
I am using the dataset
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00477/ in this link.
I will be grateful if you could help me.

index.hmtl and app.py

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- JS & CSS library of MultiSelect plugin -->
    <script src="multiselect/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="multiselect/jquery.multiselect.css">
    {{data | safe}}
    <style>
        .container{
            padding:20px;
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="" action="data" method="post">
    
        <input type="file" name="upload_file" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="upload_file" value="submit">
    
    </form>  
    
    <div class="container">
    <select name="x_columns[]" multiple id="x">
    <option value="X1">X1</option>
    <option value="X2">X2</option>
    <option value="X3">X3</option>
    <option value="X4">X4</option>
    <option value="X5">X5</option>
    <option value="X6">X6</option>
    <option value="Y">Y</option>
    </select>
    <script>
    $('#x_columns[]').multiselect({
        columns: 1,
        placeholder: 'Select X Columns'
    });
</script></div> 

      
<div class="container">
    <select name="y_columns[]" multiple id="y">
    <option value="X1">X1</option>
    <option value="X2">X2</option>
    <option value="X3">X3</option>
    <option value="X4">X4</option>
    <option value="X5">X5</option>
    <option value="X6">X6</option>
    <option value="Y">Y</option>
</select>
<script>
    $('#y_columns[]').multiselect({
        columns: 1,
        placeholder: 'Select Y Columns'
    });
</script></div> 
<p name="y_columns[]"> dogru</p>

</body>
</html>



import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
from pyGRNN import GRNN
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as MSE
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/data',methods=['GET','POST'])
def show_data():
 
    if request.method=='POST':
        file=request.form['upload_file']
        data=pd.read_excel(file)
        #return render_template('index.html',data=data.to_html())

        x_names=[]
        
        y_names=[]
        x_names=request.form['x_columns[]']
        print(x_names)
        y_names=request.form['y_columns[]']
        print(y_names)
        
        X=data[x_names]
        Y=data[y_names]
        x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(preprocessing.minmax_scale(X),  Y,    test_size=0.2,)
        IGRNN = GRNN(bnds=(0, None), calibration='None', kernel='RBF', method='L-BFGS-B',
                    n_restarts_optimizer=0, n_splits=5, seed=42, sigma=input)  
        IGRNN.fit(x_train, y_train.ravel())
        y_pred = IGRNN.predict(x_test)
        mse_IGRNN = MSE(y_test, y_pred)
        
        return render_template('index.html',mse_IGRNN,data=data.to_html())

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you provide your logs or errors?

Comment: * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jun/2022 09:45:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jun/2022 09:45:18] "GET /multiselect/jquery.multiselect.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jun/2022 09:45:18] "GET /multiselect/jquery.multiselect.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jun/2022 09:45:27] "POST /data HTTP/1.1" 400 -

Comment: In terminal, I see this message. In website I get  "Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."